# Write a list demultiplexer

Tags: haskell, data-structures, multiplexing

I'm trying to process the channels of an audio signal. I get the signal as list of frames where each frame has a sample for each channel. Now I would like to process the streams independently then merge them again. So I want

```
type Sample = Double
type Frame = [Sample]
type Stream = [Sample]
mux :: [Stream] -> [Frame]
demux :: [Frame] -> [Stream]
process :: Stream -> Stream

output = (mux . (map process) . demux) input

mux [[0.1, -0.1, -0.3], [0.2, 0.4, 0.6]] = [[0.1, 0.2], [-0.1, 0.4], [-0.3, 0.6]]
demux [[0.1, 0.2], [-0.1, 0.4], [-0.3, 0.6]] = [[0.1, -0.1, -0.3], [0.2, 0.4, 0.6]]
```

Because the streams are long, `mux` and `demux` must be lazy and not evaluate the whole list.

The multiplexer seems straightforward. The only thing I don't like about this version is the hard-to-read pattern matching.

```
mux streams@((_:_):_) = map head streams : mux (map tail streams)
mux _ = []
```

However I can't readily come up with a demultiplexer that would turn a list of frames into a list of streams. Since in my case there won't be more than two streams (stereo audio), I think I could manage by writing two demuxers, `monoDemux` and `stereoDemux`. But I would like one function to work on any number of channels. How can I lazily demux a list of frames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that work has already been done for you: both `mux` and `demux`, are actually just [**`transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) functions:

```
import Data.List(transpose)

mux = transpose
demux = transpose
```

This thus means that multiplexing is actually (at least in terms of a list of list) the same as demultiplexing.

It generates the expected:

```
Prelude Data.List> transpose [[0.1, -0.1, -0.3], [0.2, 0.4, 0.6]]
[[0.1,0.2],[-0.1,0.4],[-0.3,0.6]]
Prelude Data.List> transpose [[0.1, 0.2], [-0.1, 0.4], [-0.3, 0.6]]
[[0.1,-0.1,-0.3],[0.2,0.4,0.6]]
```

`transpose` works in a lazy manner. We can inspect the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#transpose):

> ```
> transpose               :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
> transpose []             = []
> transpose ([]   : xss)   = transpose xss
> transpose ((x:xs) : xss) = (x : [h | (h:_) <- xss]) : transpose (xs : [ t | (_:t) <- xss])
> ```

The last statement is a complex version of:

```
transpose l = map head l : transpose (map tail l)
```

Comment: Beautiful, I never saw multiplexing that way! Even my own function works both ways and I didn't notice. (And I still don't understand why. Have to work it out on paper.)

Comment: Does this definition mean that `transpose` is a partial function? I mean, if I say `transpose [ [1], [] ]`, it will break, right?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: no, as the documentation says: "*If some of the rows are shorter than the following rows, their elements are skipped:*". The given defintion will indeed error, but apparently the source code has been updated. The `transpose [[1],[]]` produces `[[1]]`.